# SQLInjection against CosmosDB in an Azure function

Tags: azure, sql-injection, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I have implemented an Azure function that is triggered by a HttpRequest. A parameter called `name` is passed as part of the HttpRequest. In **`Integration`** section, I have used the following query to retrieve data from CosmosDB (as an input):

```
SELECT * FROM c.my_collection pm 
WHERE
Contains(pm.first_name,{name})
```

As you see I am sending the 'name' without `sanitizing` it. Is there any `SQLInjection` concern here?

I searched and noticed that `parameterization` is available but that is not something I can do anything about here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the binding occurs ([the data from the HTTP Trigger gets sent to the Cosmos DB Input bind](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/v2.x/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB/DocumentDBSqlResolutionPolicy.cs#L35-L44)), it is passed through a `SQLParameterCollection` that will handle sanitization.

Please view [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-sql-parameterization-in-documentdb/):

> Parameterized SQL provides robust handling and escaping of user input, preventing accidental exposure of data through “SQL injection”

This will cover any attempt to inject SQL through the `name` property.

Comment: For the function binding attribute (CosmosDBAttribute  in this case), if the property in question (ie, SqlQuery)  has an [AutoResolve] attribute with a ResolutionPolicyType, it can do this sort of protection.   See   https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/CosmosDBAttribute.cs#L102

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos instead of Microsoft.Azure.Documents:

```csharp
public class MyContainerDbService : IMyContainerDbService
{
    private Container _container;

    public MyContainerDbService(CosmosClient dbClient)
    {
        this._container = dbClient.GetContainer("MyDatabaseId", "MyContainerId");
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyEntry>> GetMyEntriesAsync(string queryString, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        if ((parameters?.Count ?? 0) < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameters are required to prevent SQL injection.");
        }
        var queryDef = new QueryDefinition(queryString);
        foreach(var parm in parameters)
        {
            queryDef.WithParameter(parm.Key, parm.Value);
        }
        var query = this._container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyEntry>(queryDef);
        List<MyEntry> results = new List<MyEntry>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var response = await query.ReadNextAsync();
            results.AddRange(response.ToList());
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Info on QueryDefinition params was difficult to find.